# How to tell what UIViewController a custom UITableViewCell Xib is on?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, xib

I want to find out what ViewController a custom Table View Cell is located on.  I'm using the UI Hierarchy inspector and I don't see the name of the View Controller, it just says UITableView as the super view of the cell.

Is there a definitive way to inspect a cell and find out what View it appears on top of? If I can't do this in the UIHierachy Inspector, how can I do this?

Comment: There's no way to find that out, however, it's trivial to add a property to the cell and store a reference to the view controller when you create the cell (exercise left to the reader).

Comment: You wrote *"all iOS devs need to deal with this on a daily basis"*. Not true. I've been developing iOS apps since 2008 and never needed to do this once. BTW - why do you need to do this? A cell shouldn't care what view controller it's in. If you think it does, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree, a cell shouldn't care what VC it is in.  I'm not trying to do anything directly with the cell- so yes, my custom cell doesn't care what VC it is in.  I'm trying to add something else to the same VC based on behavior that happens inside the cell.  In other words, I'm trying to attach additional behavior to the same parent VC of the cell.

Comment: if you are talking about storyboard you might want to check out connections inspector

Comment: I'm using xibs, not storyboards.  Why was I downvoted?  Nobody has an answer yet.

Comment: @rmaddy assuming you downvoted me, what would my alternative be? To add a view to the window, instead of the parent view controller? I know that's not a good idea.  People downvote because they're too lazy to explain why they don't think this is necessary.  Seriously community, I'm listening.  What's up, why isn't this a valid/good question?

Comment: @jungledev Nope, wasn't me.

Comment: There's generally no value in asking why people voted here - votes are anonymous by design, and people may vote for any reason they like. You've presently got two up, two down, so you're in credit - and they're only fake internet points anyway, so don't worry about it `:-)`. The only thing I'd add is we really don't want questions/answers themselves to contain complaints about voting - most readers have not voted and just want to see material related to the topic at hand.

Comment: *In other words, I'm trying to attach additional behavior to the same parent VC of the cell.* this would be a delegate or a callback. The cell wouldn't know who implements it delegate or set the callback blocks to it, yet it could trigger additional functionality without breaking MVC. it could even pass itself as an parameter, allowing the VC to directly touch it.

Comment: The phrasing of your question makes it hard to answer. "I want to find out..." If you, the programmer, want the information, then just look at the code. Maybe if you phrased the question using an object or class as the subject you would get better help (and fewer down votes.) Something like, "The table view cell needs to inform the view controller that a button was tapped on it." or something like that.

Comment: I agree with @DanielT. here, this questions asks "how" without explaining "why". While it's possible to construct or derive this relationship it's not clear that this is a reasonable thing to do. Unfortunately we don't have enough context here to evaluate that or propose alternatives. From what I see it sounds to me like this is not behavior that should be managed by a cell but instead should be implemented further up the responder chain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using Associative References. They are not pretty, and not easy to use but effective on being able to associate an object with another.

Here is a link to a tutorial on how they work.

[Associative References](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/)

After digesting this you can plan to associate the view controller / view to the tableview cell on iteration (cell for row at index path maybe)

and delegate method did select row at index path you would be able to obtain the associative reference and know what view controller needs to be manipulated.